# Aerospike UDF Logging - Elevating UDF error message

Tags: aerospike

Aerospike UDF log messages are of the form:

```
Mar 09 2016 23:32:18 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_rw.c:send_udf_failure:183) 
Non-special LDT or General UDF
Error(/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/someFile.lua:33:
bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got nil))
```

**Concern**

The issue is that these are error-type messages (they break functionality), but are logged under the DEBUG level. If one is logging at INFO or WARN levels, ideally they would be able to see "Non-special LDT or General UDF Error" messages.

**Question**

Is it possible to configure "Non-special LDT or General UDF Error" messages to log at a higher level, while keeping other truly DEBUG-level UDF messages (e.g. `urecord ... dirty(1)`) at DEBUG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set log levels by a whole context, for example

```
logging {
  file /var/log/aerospike.log {
    context any info
    context aggr critical
    context udf critical
    context query critical
  }
  file /var/log/lua.log {
    context any critical
    context aggr debug
    context udf debug
    context query debug
  }
}
```

The list of contexts is available using `asinfo -v "log/" -l`.